# Converting from JSON to Java Object

Tags: java, json, object, jackson

I am trying to convert a JSON to java object using using jackson. But I am getting null values. Here are my pojos. Please note that I have setters and getters on those 2 classes.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IncidentDetails {

    private Integer incidentTypeId;
    private String description;
    private List<IncidentEvents> incidentEventList;
```

---

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class IncidentEvents {

    private int eventId;
    private int alarmId;
    private Timestamp eventDateTime;

}
```

---

```
My Request: 
{
  "IncidentDetails": {
    "incidentTypeId": "1",
    "description": "Description",
    "IncidentEvents": 
      [
        {
          "eventId": "1",
          "alarmId": "1",
          "eventDateTime": "09/29/2016 12:00:00 AM"
        },
        {
          "eventId": "2",
          "alarmId": "2",
          "eventDateTime": "09/29/2016 12:05:00 AM"
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

And how I map it:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
IncidentDetails incident = mapper.readValue(details, IncidentDetails.class);
.....
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your JSON has an extra root element.

Comment: I always find it very *informative* for **debugging** purposes, to generate JSON from the object, to see exactly how the JSON <-> Object mapping worked out. You should try it.

Comment: Similarly, `IncidentEvents` should probably be named `incidentEventList` or vice-versa.